# Routing in MS SQL 2012

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, sql-server

I would like to perform routing in MS SQL 2012 similar to pgRouting.

In pgRouting, I'd do the following steps to create a routable network:

1. Create a database routing with template `template_routing`
2. Create table `road_network` with following constraints

   ```
   CHECK (st_ndims(the_geom) = 2)
   CHECK (geometrytype(the_geom) = 'MULTILINESTRING'::text OR the_geom IS NULL)
   CHECK (st_srid(the_geom) = 4030)

   Then
   -- @ CREATE INDEX FOR THE ROAD TABLE -------------------- IMPORTANT

   CREATE INDEX spatialindex_road
       ON road_network
       USING gist
       (the_geom);
   ```
3. Perform the following queries:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE road_network ADD COLUMN "source" integer;
   ALTER TABLE road_network ADD COLUMN "target" integer;

   SELECT assign_vertex_id('road_network', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'gid');

   CREATE INDEX source_idx ON road_network("source");
   CREATE INDEX target_idx ON road_network("target");

   ALTER TABLE road_network  ADD COLUMN length double precision;
   UPDATE road_network  SET length = length(the_geom);


   ALTER TABLE road_network  ADD COLUMN reverse_cost double precision;
   UPDATE road_network  SET reverse_cost = length;

   ALTER TABLE road_network  ADD COLUMN x1 double precision;
   ALTER TABLE road_network  ADD COLUMN y1 double precision;
   ALTER TABLE road_network  ADD COLUMN x2 double precision;
   ALTER TABLE road_network  ADD COLUMN y2 double precision;

   UPDATE road_network  SET x1 = x(ST_PointN(the_geom, 1));
   UPDATE road_network  SET y1 = y(ST_PointN(the_geom, 1));
   UPDATE road_network  SET x2 = x(ST_PointN(the_geom, ST_NumPoints(the_geom)));
   UPDATE road_network  SET y2 = y(ST_PointN(the_geom, ST_NumPoints(the_geom)));
   alter table road_network add column cost double precision default 0;
   update road_network set cost=0.1 where type='NH';
   update road_network set cost=0.2 where type='SH';
   update road_network set cost=0.3 where type='major';
   update road_network set cost=0.4 where type='minor';
   update road_network set cost=1.2 where type='colony';
   update road_network set cost=0.8 where type='third';
   ```
4. Now the network table is created.

   To check, run this query on your postgreSQL....
   assign table name name and create a table

   ```
   CREATE TABLE shortest_path_astar_table_3(gid int4) with oids;
   SELECT AddGeometryColumn( 'shortest_path_astar_table_3', 'the_geom', 4030, 'MULTILINESTRING', 2 );
   INSERT INTO shortest_path_astar_table_3(the_geom) 
   SELECT the_geom FROM astar_sp_directed('road_network',37,43,true,true);
   ```

   Open `shortest_path_astar_table_3` on QGIS and check the path.

Is there any similar way to perform similar queries in SQL Server 2012?

Comment: When you say "SQL" I assume you actually mean "MS SQL Server"? Worth being specific, since "SQL" is just a query language...

Comment: Yes it is !! Ms SQL Server 2012

Comment: There is no in database solutions for routing that i know for MS SQL. But if you have network topology table in MS SQL you can write one , or use 3rd party middleware

Comment: Can you list out the 3rd party middleware ? And how to use network topology table in MS SQL. Please share some links or steps @simplexio

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server do not support routing, afaik.